# Can't change the text of JLabel

Tags: java, jlabel

I'm trying to change the text of a JLabel but my method doesn't even see the label

In my Gui class I have

```
public void setText(String message)
    {
        label03.setText(message);
    }
```

And for my label 03 I have

```
JLabel label03 = new JLabel("0");
        label03.setIcon(icon);
        label03.setBounds(204, 130, 46, 14);
        getContentPane().add(label03);
```

I'm using WindowBuilder to do this

Am I missing something? That my method can't seem to be able to change the label text?

Comment: Post your complete code

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are declaring your variable in one method and trying to use it in another. This is a [variable scoping](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) problem.

You probably need to store your label as a field in your class, so that you can access it from multiple methods.

```
public class SomeClass {
  private JLabel label03; 

  public void someMethod() {
    label03 = new JLabel("0");
    label03.setIcon(icon);
    label03.setBounds(204, 130, 46, 14);
    getContentPane().add(label03);
  }

  public void setText(String message) {
    label03.setText(message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Regarding this, WindowBuilder normally only automatically creates fields out of text areas and text fields and other data entry GUI objects; you will have to manually move out labels and other things you want to change after initialization from the pre-defined `initialize` method. Easiest way to do it is to eliminate the class name in the `initialize()` declaration (i.e. delete `JLabel` before label03), right click, Convert to Field.